# Delphi Tokyo webbrowser how to get access to all column and rows in html document

Tags: delphi, rad, twebbrowser, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I want to get information from webpage to do it I need to list all columns and rows inside html document

I can get access to html elements by ID but how to get access to all
rows and columns   inside html code to get html code for each cell?

```
function GetElementById(const Doc: IDispatch; const Id: string;memo:tmemo): IDispatch;
var
  Document: IHTMLDocument2;     // IHTMLDocument2 interface of Doc
  Body: IHTMLElement2;          // document body element
  Tags: IHTMLElementCollection; // all tags in document body
  Tag: IHTMLElement;            // a tag in document body
  I: Integer;                   // loops thru tags in document body
begin
  Result := nil;

  // Check for valid document: require IHTMLDocument2 interface to it
  if not Supports(Doc, IHTMLDocument2, Document) then
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid HTML document');
  // Check for valid body element: require IHTMLElement2 interface to it
  if not Supports(Document.body, IHTMLElement2, Body) then
    raise Exception.Create('Can''t find <body> element');
  // Get all tags in body element ('*' => any tag name)
  Tags := Body.getElementsByTagName('*');

  // Scan through all tags in body
  for I := 0 to Pred(Tags.length) do
  begin
    // Get reference to a tag
    Tag := Tags.item(I, EmptyParam) as IHTMLElement;

    // Check tag's id and return it if id matches
    if AnsiSameText(Tag.id, Id) then
    begin
      memo.lines.add(Tag.id);
      memo.Lines.Add(tag.outerHTML);
      Result := Tag;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: we need a bit more context here, what are you trying to do? maybe add some html to highlight the problem?

Comment: ` how to get access to all rows and columns?`  Do you mean the rows and columns of any table(s) the page contains, or what?